# Highchart: Center text in series Data Name

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

```
      series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        data: [ {
            name: 'Safari <br> (N=6)',
            y: 4.77,
            count:600,

        }, {
            name: 'Opera <br> (N=60)',
            y: 0.91,
             count:800,

        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable <br> (N=6)',
            y: 0.2,
             count:60,

        }]
    }]
```

I want to display  (N=6) in the center of "Proprietary or Undetectable"

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2a1yk8cn/2/)

Comment: I'm afraid there's no 'simple' sustainable solution, would this charts properties ever changes, then there is no way of automatically adjusting it. your `text-anchor: middle` isn't working on the N=6

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2a1yk8cn/3/

Comment: @DipaliVasani : i want  (N=6) in middle of  "Proprietary or Undetectable" on y-axis

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2a1yk8cn/6/)